# iOS MVC - Passing data back and forth to view controllers and model

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, model-view-controller

I'm new to iOS programming and having written a simple reminders style app, I'm now rewriting it to implement the MVC model correctly as previously all my code was inside View Controllers.

I have a custom class called Event with properties name, time, repeat etc and then the following structure:

**Model class**

Retrieves, processes and and saves data to and from `NSUserDefaults`

**RootViewController**

Creates an instance of the Model object and asks the model to return all the Events objects from `NSUserDefaults` then displays them in a `UITableView`

**EditEventViewController**

`[editEventVC initWithEvent:theEvent];`

Passes the specific event object that was selected in the table cell via init method and displays all the properties available for editing

**EditEventPropertyViewController**

`[editEventPropertyVC initWithValue:propertyValue];`

Passes value of property to edit (e.g. event name) via init method and returns the user updated value via a delegate method

Is this the correct way to implement this app?

What's the best way to save the updated Event object in `NSUserDefaults` via the Model after finishing with the EditEventViewController?  Via a delegate?  Currently I am reloading the uitableview data on viewWillAppear in the rootViewController so it will have to save the updated data before retrieving it again.

Thanks

Comment: I dont prefer to use nsdata as my "Persistant" storage. its good for settings though why dont you try core data

Comment: @amar - thanks, yes I am planning to use Core Data once I have this working, but I assume the principals are the same with regards to the structure?

Comment: You can use delegate methods or notificationr to do the data passing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store the collection of `Event` in `NSUserDefaults`. Since its a custom class, you need to implement `NSCoding` protocol for serialization to `NSUserDefaults`.

```
//Event.h

    @interface Event : NSObject<NSCoding>

    @property (nonatomic, copy)   NSString *name;
    @property (nonatomic, strong) NSDate *time;
    @property (nonatomic) NSInteger repeat;

    - (void)save;
    + (NSArray *)allEvents;

//Event.m
#define kSavedEvents @"SavedEvents"

#pragma mark - Encoding
- (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)encoder
{
    [encoder encodeObject:self.name  forKey:@"EventName"];
    [encoder encodeObject:self.time forKey:@"EventTime"];
    [encoder encodeObject:@(self.repeat) forKey:@"EventRepeat"];

}

#pragma mark - Decoding
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)decoder
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self)
    {
        _name   = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"EventName"];
        _time   = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"EventTime"];
        _repeat = [[decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"EventRepeat"]integerValue];

    }
    return self;
}
```

You need to archive the data while storing to NSUserDefaults and unarchive when fetching

```
 (void)save
{
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

    NSData *savedData = [defaults objectForKey:kSavedEvents];


    NSMutableArray *savedEvents = [@[] mutableCopy];

    //Some events are already there in there
    if (savedData) {
        savedEvents = [[NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:savedData]mutableCopy];
    }

    [savedEvents addObject:self];

    //Archiving the savedEvents to data
    NSData *newEventData = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:savedEvents];

    [defaults setObject:newEventData forKey:kSavedEvents];
    [defaults synchronize];
}

+ (NSArray *)allEvents
{
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSData *data = [defaults objectForKey:kSavedEvents];
    if (data)
    {
        return [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:data];
    }
    return nil;
}
```

Hope this will get you started.

Comment: thanks - actually I had not yet realised I would have a problem with storing custom objects in NSUserDefaults so thank you for this! However, my question was about passing the data back and forth - does my structure look correct?

Comment: @fxfuture I believe this solution would still hold good for that. For eg. if you are in FirstViewController and you create an event, save it there. On SecondViewController you can fetch the saved event there and edit and resave it. Or the other way is to create a property to hold event in SecondViewController, while instantiation set the value of event from FirstViewController.