# Store user info at login for later use

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I am building an app where at login, the correct combination of username/password returns some basic user info (firstName, lastName, userType, companyID, etc).

I will be needing those values and strings throughout my application to retrieve user-specific data.

Could I store all those values and strings at login in an NSObject or NSData subclass so that I can later call it to retrieve the items I need? How can I do this? or is there a better alternative?

Comment: you would store it in **1.** user default, or **2.** keychain. it depends on what you need.

Comment: You can save the data in NSUserDefaults. I have made a recent post on how to store a custom class in NSUserDefaults http://stackoverflow.com/a/15242939/767730 .

Comment: Note that NSUserDefaults disappears when the app is uninstalled; the keychain values are preserved instead.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are just storing the data returned from a successful login like you say, First Name, Last Name etc. I would use NSUserDefaults. 
If you intend to store any sensitive information such as username or password or anything else  requiring additional confidentiality I would recommend using the keychain.

Answer (score 4):

I would use Keychain since it is secure. Check this [STKeychain](https://github.com/ldandersen/STUtils/blob/master/Security/STKeychain.h)

Comment: Keychain is secure but don't put all your trust in it: http://www.raywenderlich.com/45645/ios-app-security-analysis-part-1

Answer (score 3):

You can use `NSUserDefaults`. Create a User Model. Implement `NSCoding` protocol. Archive while storing and unarchive while fetching from `NSUserDefaults`.

```
@interface User: NSObject<NSCoding>

    @property (nonatomic, copy)   NSString *firstName;
    @property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *lastName;

    - (void)save;
    + (id)savedUser;
```

//User.m

```
#define kSavedUser @"SavedUser"

#pragma mark - Encoding
- (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)encoder
{
    [encoder encodeObject:self.firstName forKey:@"FirstName"];
    [encoder encodeObject:self.lastName forKey:@"LastName"]

}

#pragma mark - Decoding
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)decoder
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self)
    {
        _firstName   = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"FirstName"];
        _lastName   = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"LastName"];

    }
    return self;
}


-(void)save
{
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSData *data = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:self];
    [defaults setObject:data forKey:kSavedUser];
    [defaults synchronize];
}

+ (id)savedUser
{
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSData *data = [defaults objectForKey:kSavedUser];
    if (data)
    {
        return [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:data];
    }
    return nil;
}

+ (void)clearUser
{
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [defaults removeObjectForKey:kSavedUser];
    [defaults synchronize];
}
```

Now you can create an instance of

```
User *user = [[User alloc]init];
user.firstName = @"";
user.lastName = @"";
[user save];
```

When you want to retrieve

```
User *user = [User savedUser];
```

EDIT: 
If you want to clear the data, call the static method to remove saved user info

```
[User clearUser];
```