# When I want to cache some data in my iPhone app, sqlite or just JSON file?

Tags: ios, sqlite, caching

I have some data want to cache in my iPhone app, the date change not so often.

I want to use SQLite to store them, but SQLite will start in application cost some memory, and if it is not necessary?

Can I use simple txt file to store data like JSON format? I still worry about I will manage file's open, write, reads cost, etc.

Comment: How much data do you need to store? If the data is very little you can use NSUserDefaults.

Comment: @Anupdas not so much, but I think NSUserDefaults is not so good for structured data

Comment: You can store structured data very well into NSUserDefaults. You need to implement NSCoding protocol and implement serialization/deserialization methods thats it. I had given a similar answer, you may want to look it http://stackoverflow.com/a/15242939/767730